# Electron - Webcam not working in windows (getUserMedia - Uncaught DOMException: Could not start video source)

Tags: electron, webcam, electron-builder, getusermedia

Electron-Builder Version: 23.6.0
Node Version: v20.4.0
Electron Version: 23.3.10
Electron Type (current, beta, nightly): current
Target: nsis

Hello, the webcam does not work in the version for Windows, which is built through nsis.
Although it works on macOS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtCS5.png)

But audio work and screen sharing work too.

Tell me what can be done about it?

I tried to sign the application, change the versions of the node, electron...